# How to get out data from completion handler

Tags: swift, completionhandler

I am trying to get a function that calls an API via HTTP request and return a String. My request function has a completion handler that returns the Data and it is used by my function.

```
func buildHTML () -> String {
    var htmlString: String = ""

    request(url: "https://someurl.com/api/getalldata") { (jsonData: Data) in
        let units = try JSONDecoder().decode([MyUnits].self, from: jsonData)
            for unit in units {
                //Building my html string here
                htmlString += "......."
            }
    }
    return htmlString
}
```

However this does not work, because the htmlString returned as an empty string, How can I get this string out to return it by buildHTML?

Any idea is welcomed!

Answer (score 4):

Since your request is asynchronous you will not be able to return a result as your return statement will execute before your closure is executed.  The solution, in this case, is to use a completion handler in your outer function as well:

```
func buildHTML(_ completion: @escaping (String)->Void) {
    var htmlString: String = ""

    request(url: "https://someurl.com/api/getalldata") { (jsonData: Data) in
        let units = try JSONDecoder().decode([MyUnits].self, from: jsonData)
            for unit in units {
                //Building my html string here
                htmlString += "......."
            }
        completion(htmlString)
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not want to do that, but sounds like there is no other way. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

My solution will block the current thread, but it is synchronous. You can use Data.

```
func buildHTML(_ completion: @escaping (String)->Void) {
    var htmlString: String = ""
    let url = URL(string: "https://someurl.com/api/getalldata")!

    guard let jsonData = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
        print("There was an error!")
        // return or break
    }

    let units = try JSONDecoder().decode([MyUnits].self, from: jsonData)
    for unit in units {
        //Building my html string here
        htmlString += "......."
    }
    completion(htmlString)
}
```